# Boot loader failure and reinstalling help

Tags: system-installation

After being fed up with windows and seeing Ubuntu 14.04, I downloaded 15.04 iso from ubuntu.com and used pendrivelinux.com(was listed on Ubuntu website) to create a bootable usb.
During installation after choosing "something else" and using one for my partition for root (ext4 journal) grub failed to install. 
I couldn't use Ubuntu and neither windows. I had to reformat the two partitions containing Ubuntu and Windows, somehow recovered my data using Easeus.

So now I have backed up important stuff and want to reinstall ubuntu, only ubuntu. 
This being my home computer my dad uses it for general stuff like pdfs and office files(doc,ppt...). 
I currently have 3 partitions one.having windows 7, one for my personal data and the last one is blank.
Now I want to install ubuntu fresh without losing data of the second partition. No dual boot necessary,just ubuntu. 
Since ubuntu uses ext 4 will I ever be able to return to windows?

Since I used a 3g micromax dongle on windows for internet, how would I be able to configure it on Ubuntu? 
Without Internet won't be able to install any packages and would be locked out. Does ubuntu come preinstalled with a pdf reader as with libre office?

My computer has 2 gigs of ram and a 250 gig hard drive. 
Intel core 2 duo @ ~2.5 Ghz.
Came preinstalled with Vista but now I use 7.

Comment: If system with only 2GB of RAM, and probably a more limited video card or chip, you need to install Lubuntu or Xubuntu. On my similar laptop, I was able to get Ubuntu to install but it was so slow to be unusable. I then installed fallback or gnome-panel which is another light weight gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you just want Ubuntu.

> When you get up to this stage click something else click contiune

[image]

> Then Select Free space and create a new Partition

[image]

> Create a new partition take 1000 MB off the Size. use as an EXT4, use
>   / as the mount point

[image]

> Create a Swap Partition

[image]

> Now make sure Ubuntu has selected the right device for the grub boot
>   loader  so if your drive is called /dev/sda you don't want to install
>   the boot loader to a partition is may cause problems  so if ubuntu
>   selected the boot loader to be installed on /dev/sda1 you need to
>   change it to /dev/sda

[image]

If the boot loader fails to install after flowing these steps take a screen shot or even better copy the error and post it here.

Comment: So will it be able to access data from the partition which has been formatted to NTFS (by default) by windows?And if I choose erase disk and install ubuntu (I have backed up my stuff), wouldn't it be better to perform a clean installation?

Comment: you said you have 3 partitions one having windows 7, one for you're personal data and one being blank. Install Ubuntu on the Blank partition. Ubuntu wont touch  the other 2 partitions. And this is a clean installation for Ubuntu.

Comment: To create swap space should I leave some unallocated space through the windows partition manager?

Comment: If I later decide that I don't need windows any more would simply formatting windows' partition through ubuntu be enough?

Comment: Now that I think of it, my windows 7 is 32 bit and the Ubuntu iso I have is actually 64 bit, would dual booting create that same bootloader problem again?

Comment: To Create Swap you should leave some unallocated space.

Comment: If you later decide that you don't need windows any more formatting windows through Ubuntu will be just fine.

Comment: it doesn’t matter if you dual boot with a 32bit version of windows or a 64bit version of windows it wont make any difference.

Comment: Right. Then gonna try it. Thanks though!